# How to implement my MVP / Rxswift with Combine

Tags: swift, rx-swift, combine

usually I organize my code (in a simplified way) like that :

Presenter Subscribe to my Model (via Managers)

```
myManager.getItems(...).subscribe { .... }.disposed()
```

The Manager call getItems from a Provider and transform DTO -> BO :

```
func getItems(...) -> Single<myObectBO> {
    myProvider.getItems(...).map { myDTO in
        return MyObjectBO(withDTO: myDTO)
    }
}
```

The Provider return a Single of DTO:

```
func getItems(...) -> Single<myObectDTO> {
    ...
    return Single.just(myObectDTO)
}
```

I tried different thing but for the moment I've found nothing to implement that in Combine, is there a simple way to do this?
Thank you for your help.

---

To be more clear I want to do something like that :

```
func getSomething() {
    getManagerFuture()
        .sink { result in
            print(result)
        }
}

func getManagerFuture() -> Future<[MyBO], ManagerError> {
    
    Future { promise in
    getProviderFuture()
        .flatMap { dtoList -> ([MyBO], ManagerError) in
            
            let boList = dtoList.map { dto in
                return MyBO(id: dto.id, name: dto.name)
            }
            
            return promise(.success(boList))
        }
    }
}

func getProviderFuture() -> Future<[MyDTO], ProviderError> {

    // should be a webservice call
    
    let dto1 = MyDTO(id: 1, name: "one")
    let dto2 = MyDTO(id: 2, name: "two")
    
    return Future { promise in promise(.success([dto1, dto2])) }
}
```

I have this errors on getManagerProvider :

> Instance method 'flatMap(maxPublishers:_:)' requires the types
> '([MyBO], ManagerError).Failure' and 'Never' be equivalent
>
> Type '([MyBO], ManagerError)' cannot conform to 'Publisher'; only
> struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Comment: Implement what exactly? Where exactly is the complication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something like this, that is woking fine in playground.

For precision, it's good practice to erase publishers, to be able to change your implementation without changing outside of your code

```
enum DTOError: Error {
  case wrongDTO
}

enum BOError: Error {
  case wrongBO
}

struct DTO {
  let value = "Value"
}

struct BO {
  let value: String
  init(dto: DTO) {
    self.value = dto.value
  }
}

func getDTO() -> AnyPublisher<DTO, DTOError> {
  Future { promise in
    promise(.success(DTO()))
  }
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func getBO() -> AnyPublisher<BO, BOError> {
  getDTO()
    .flatMap({ dto -> Future<BO, DTOError> in
      Future<BO, DTOError> { promise in
        promise(.success(BO(dto: dto)))
      }
    })
    .mapError { dtoError -> BOError in
      .wrongBO
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

getBO()
  .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
    print(completion)
  }) { data in
    print(data)
  }
```

There may be a more concise solution though